# Action Script 3. Delete object when mouse clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, actionscript

I'm creating flash game, Idea is falling objects (in this case apples) from the sky and player need to click on apples, after apple is clicked It must be deleted and Score updated by 10 points.

Here is my part of code where apples is spawning:

```
  public function startGame()
            {
                speed = C.PLAYER_SPEED;
                gravity = C.GRAVITY;
                score = C.PLAYER_START_SCORE;
                randomChance = C.APPLE_SPAWN_CHANCE;
                apples = new Array();

                mcGameStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);

            }       

            private function update(evt:Event)
            {

                //Spawn new apples
                if (Math.random() < randomChance)
                {
                    var newApple = new Apple();
                    newApple.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;

                    newApple.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
                    apples.push(newApple);

                    mcGameStage.addChildAt(newApple,0);
                }           
                //Move Apples
                for (var i = apples.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    apples[i].y += gravity;

                    if (apples[i].y > C.APPLE_END_Y)
                    {
                        mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[i]);
                        apples.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }           


                //txtScore.text = String(score);
            }

        }
```

And here is code which should delete apples by mouse clicked. But It doesn't work, I  don't have any errors, just not deleting apples. Could you help me please?

```
function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
            var apples = evt.target;

                for (var iz = apples.length-1; iz >= 0; iz--)
                {
                        //Register hit
                        score += C.SCORE_PER_APPLE;                 
                        mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[iz]);                
                        apples.splice(iz,1);        
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE**

So my code now looks like:

```
        public function startGame()
        {
            speed = C.PLAYER_SPEED;
            gravity = C.GRAVITY;
            score = C.PLAYER_START_SCORE;
            randomChance = C.APPLE_SPAWN_CHANCE;
            apples = new Array();

            mcGameStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);

        }       

        private function update(evt:Event)
        {

            //Spawn new apples
            if (Math.random() < randomChance)
            {
                var newApple = new Apple();
                newApple.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;

                newApple.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
                apples.push(newApple);
                newApple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

                mcGameStage.addChildAt(newApple,0);
            }           
            //Move Apples
            for (var i = apples.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                apples[i].y += gravity;

                if (apples[i].y > C.APPLE_END_Y)
                {
                    mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[i]);

                    apples.splice(i,1);
                }
            }           


            txtScore.text = String(score);
        }
        function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
            var apples = evt.target;
        apples.visible = false;
        //mcGameStage.removeChild(apples);      
        score += C.SCORE_PER_APPLE; 

        }
    }
}
```

I use this `apples.visible = false;` instead `mcGameStage.removeChild(apples);` and It's all right.
Just I misunderstood why my score not updating? Always show 0.
And sometimes I can't set apples invisible by 1 click If it is click on top of apple nothing happens, I need to click on apple's center to hide It, why I have this problem?

Comment: When you change the score (i.e. in onClick) and check the value right after that, is it still zero then? Where did you define score?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I fixed It, this was because in textField was typed "0", when I deleted It, now counting correctly.

Comment: So, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private function update(evt:Event)
        {

            //Spawn new apples
            if (Math.random() < randomChance)
            {
                var newApple = new Apple(appleClick);
                newApple.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;

                newApple.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
                apples.push(newApple);
                mcGameStage.addChildAt(newApple,0);
            }           
            //Move Apples
            for (var i = apples.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                apples[i].y += gravity;

                if (apples[i].y > C.APPLE_END_Y)
                {
                    mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[i]);
                    apples[iz].destruct();
                    apples.splice(i,1);
                }
            }           


            //txtScore.text = String(score);
        }

        function appleClick(pApple:Apple):void{
            for (var iz = apples.length-1; iz >= 0; iz--)
            {
                    if (apples[iz] == pApple)
                    {
                        //Register hit
                        score += C.SCORE_PER_APPLE;                 
                        mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[iz]);
                        apples[iz].destruct();
                        apples.splice(iz,1);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

....

```
public class Apple extends Group or something
{
    private var m_fCallback:Function;

    public function Apple(pCallback:Function):void
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        m_fCallback = pCallback;
    }

    private function destruct():void
    {
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    }

    private function onClick(pEvent:MouseEvent):void
    {
        m_fCallback(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, now when I use trace onClick function `trace("test");` It writes correctly, just not remove apples

Comment: Edited again for other reasons.  Sorry I keep getting distracted by stuff going on at the office and am not having an easy time right now proofreading the answer.  Sorry, I kind of got rushed into hurrying up and posting the answer, but I'll try to check it over again in a bit.  The main problem was that the apples weren't having event listeners added to them.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I misunderstood why do you created new class? Is this case better? I updated my question how my code looks like now.

Comment: Rather inefficient with regards to memory and (probably) runtime speed.

Comment: Alright, this code should be good now.  It looked from your code like Apple was already a separate class, and I'm personally not used to using Event.target (though I probably should be), so I couldn't rely on giving you an answer that used it.  You seemed to mention in your edit that clicking stacked apples only deals with one of them at a time; the click event will only go to whatever UIComponent's on the very top of everything else, so you'll have to add special logic to handle that.

Comment: The score problem exists outside of the scope of the current code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serious about game development, you should think about code bloat. In your case, you don't need any `apples` array - your display list, courtesy Flash Player, is already able to contain the apples in a sorted linked list structure - much more efficient for the kind  use you intend for it - deleting and adding apples. If you dedicate a container sprite just for containing apples, you get two benefits: 1) you get a free display list of apples and 2) if you register a mouse click event listener for this sprite (which contains only apples), then every click is on an apple and `event.target` will reflect it.

Review the altered code carefully:

```
public function startGame()
{
    speed = C.PLAYER_SPEED;
    gravity = C.GRAVITY;
    score = C.PLAYER_START_SCORE;
    randomChance = C.APPLE_SPAWN_CHANCE;

    mcApples = new Sprite();
    mcApples.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickApple);

    mcGameStage.addChild(mcApples);

    mcGameStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}

private function update(evt:Event)
{
    //Spawn new apple
    if(Math.random() < randomChance)
    {
        var newApple = new Apple();

        newApple.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        newApple.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;

        mcApples.addChild(newApple);
    }

    //Move Apples
    for (var i = 0; i < mcApples.numChildren;)
    {
        var apple = mcApples.getChildAt(i);

        apple.y += gravity;

        if(apple.y > C.APPLE_END_Y)
        {
            apple.parent.removeChild(apple);
            continue;
        }

        i++;
    }
}

function onClickApple(event: MouseEvent):void
{
    var apple : Apple = event.target;

    apple.parent.removeChild(apple);

    score += C.SCORE_PER_APPLE;
}
```

The important changes and their effects are thus:

1. Dedicated sprite `mcApples` where apples are added and removed from.
2. No need for an array of apples, Flash Player keeps track of apples in `mcApples` container.
3. Mouse clicking listener setup guarantees any click is on an apple.

So, no splicing of arrays required and no need for explicit function references in `Apple` class or adding event listener for each new apple.

As an extra piece of advice, you should be careful binding your logic to `enter frame` events - the faster the frame rate, the faster the call frequency - usually no problem, but sometimes not what you want. I would bind the `update` call to a timer event instead ;-)

Comment: Thank you, but I got few errors while using this:
http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/1463/qqqzi.png

Comment: Maybe I need to add `private var mcApples:....` but I don't know which type to use `:Object` or `:ContainerController`, but these doesn't work.

Comment: Well, display objects that may contain other objects, of which `Sprite`'s are an example, are all subclassed from `DisplayObjectContainer`, but since it is an abstract class, we use `Sprite`. So, `var mcApples: Sprite`. Also, I wrote the example off the top of my head, never having compiled it. I trust you know how to fix the compilation errors, consider it an exercise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any event listener added for **onClick()**. Be sure to check that your event listener is added, and put a trace or an alert in your **onClick()** function so that you can confirm that the code is actually reached.

Comment: Thank you for answer, now when I use trace onClick function trace("test"); It writes correctly, just not remove apples

Comment: You can try setting the apples visibility to false to see if that makes a difference. Otherwise it must be trying to remove the wrong apple.

Comment: Thanks all right with set visible to false. Maybe do you know whats wrong when I click on top of apple it not hiding, I must click to center of apple to hide it.

Comment: And maybe do you know why my score not changing, always show 0

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing where exactly you are putting the event listener.